# Print sections that were hidden on the screen with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have run into a small problem I have not encountered before: I use javascript (jQuery) to show different sections of information in tabs on a web-page. So what I´m doing, is hiding the tabs that are not being viewed and only showing the tab that is being viewed.

This works very well, but now I am adding a print-specific style-sheet and I want to print the information of all tabs and not just the one being viewed.

How can I undo the javascript hiding of these sections for the print style-sheet?

**Edit:** Some additional information:

I am using jQuery to hide all `div.tabs sections` and in my print style-sheet I have set:

```
.wrapper div.tabs sections {
    display: block;
}
```

assuming that the higher value of `.wrapper div.tabs sections` compared to `div.tabs sections` would make the sections visible. But it doesn´t...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to change the JavaScript so that it modified the classes that applied to the elements and didn't modify `.style.display`. Then you could target elements with those classes differently with the screen and print media stylesheets.

The quick and dirty approach would be to use `!important` in your print media stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, `!important` works! I have edited my question but now I´m confused as to why `!important` works, but my more specific / higher value selector does not.

Comment: By the way, your best approach seems the logical way to go, why didn´t I think of that...

Comment: @jeroen — nothing is more specific than the style attribute, and `.style.foo` modifies the style attribute. Whatever you are doing with jQuery is almost certainly modifying `.style.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is CSS. Just define some things that show when printed.

Heres and example:

```
@media print {
    div.print_show{ dispay: block; }
    span.print_show{ display: inline; }
    .print_hide{ display: none; }
}
```

Comment: That´s exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Yes, I´ve tried to explain it a little better with my last edit.

Comment: Sorry, i'll edit. But maybe you should accept Davids answer if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @David Dorward's class swapping solution seems best.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra class to add display:block to your print.css..

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that after loading of the DOM, javascript is setting the `display` of that same section to `none` regardless what I set in the style-sheet.